# Как сделать scrollbar поверх окна на css html?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать scrollbar поверх окна на css html?
[image]

Comment: К сожалению, такие скролл бары без js не сделать. Можно использовать библиотеки. Например, jQuery NiceScroll Plugin. И честно, я бы от дизайнеров требовал выдавать на использование библиотеки, а потом самим решать проблемы с их интеграцией.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Долго искал ответ на єтот вопрос но так и ненашол ответ. Реализовал на js спомощю плагина [perfect-scrollbar](https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/)